# NetworkStream.ReadAsync in C# is not reading properly and only with debugging

Tags: c#, tcp

I'm making a TCP server, which handles async writing and reading. When a client is connected it will start listening to messages with "readAsync".

```
        public async void ReadClientDataAsync()
        {
            int result = 1;
            while (result != 0)
            {
                if (networkStream.DataAvailable)
                {
                    byte[] data = new byte[4096];


                    result = await networkStream.ReadAsync(data, 0, data.Length);
                    Debug.WriteLine(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data));

                }
            }
            networkStream.Dispose();
            tcpClient.Dispose();
            Console.WriteLine("DONE");


        }
```

This is not working. It is so strange that only works when I "step into" debug. I'm not sure what's going on.

I'm using netcat to test this out, no need to write a client.

Comment: No, it's not strange. You just have to pay attention to the official documentation that specifies the valid behavior(s) of the Read/ReadAsync method: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.networkstream.readasync : "_reads as much data as is available, up to the number of bytes specified by the size parameter_". Note that this behavior does not guarantee that a single call of ReadAsync will read `data.Length` bytes...

Comment: I read that, and tried with only one byte and the behavior is the same. @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace

Comment: Okay, what **precisely** is the problem then? "_Not properly reading_" and "_This is not working_" is not very informative (it basically just says "i have some problem with reading from a Networkstream" and nothing more), and it doesn't tell how the stuff is going wrong, what you observe, and what your expectations are with regard to what you would consider "proper behavior". Please edit your question and add these clarifications to it.

Comment: It is only receiving the data that I sent before "readasync" is executed. Every piece of data I send after readasync is executed is lost. I'm not really sure how. @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace.
Even if I use ```byte[] data = new byte[tcpClient.Available];``` which has the number of the bytes received from the client, it will only receive the bytes that were sent before readAsync is executed

Comment: The weirdest thing is that appears to only work when I use the debugger.

Comment: I guess you need to add details to your question about how you are using netcat. Not sure it is related to netcat, but for someone not seeing what you saw and did it can't be ruled it out either...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248160/discussion-between-myskullcaveisadarkplace-and-hamon).

Comment: `public async void` should be `public async Task...`. Also `Debug.WriteLine(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data));` should be `Debug.WriteLine(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, i));` And `tcpClient` and `networkStream` need `using` to dispose them. And `if (networkStream.DataAvailable)` is not necessary as `ReadAsync` will block until data is available anyway. None of these is likely your problem (which is completely unclear) but should be fixed anyway

Comment: TCP you can receive data with no length which is a KEEP-ALIVE.  Your code is wrong.  Looping using  "while (result != 0)" is wrong.   TCP a message is broken into datagrams and you have no control where or when the messages are split. So you only can tell when a message is complete by one of three methods 1) Terminate message is an end character(s) 2) Add a byte count to beginning of message and read until all bytes are received 3) Use fixed length messages.  Using debug mode you are slowing down application so code will get all the data in one chunk instead of the way windows operates.